# Prometheus - condition based on label arithmetics

Tags: prometheus, promql

Let's suppose I have a metric `my_metric` and would like to calculate a difference between current metric and the one from two days ago based on label `my_label`. Is there a way to do it in PromQL without hardcoding the label values?

```
my_metric{exported_job="my_job",instance="dr01:9091",job="pushgateway",my_label="2020-05-01"}   10
my_metric{exported_job="my_job",instance="dr01:9091",job="pushgateway",my_label="2020-05-02"}   20
my_metric{exported_job="my_job",instance="dr01:9091",job="pushgateway",my_label="2020-05-03"}   60
```

Let's suppose we're at `2020-05-01` - the expected output would be `60-10 = 50`.

In other words - I need a query, which in SQL would be something like:

```
SELECT m_2.value - m_1.value FROM my_metric m_1, my_metric m_2 
WHERE diff_date('day', m_2.my_label, m_1.my_label) = 2
```

Comment: So your basic issue is that you want to perform a time-based comparison, but using a label as "true" timestamp rather than the timestamp at which the metric was scraped? This is a known matter, see https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway/blob/master/README.md#about-timestamps https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway/issues/109

Answer (score 0):

this would give you a diff between the time you call the query and the metric value and 2days before:

```
my_metric{exported_job="my_job",instance="dr01:9091",job="pushgateway"}
- ignoring(my_label) my_metric{exported_job="my_job",instance="dr01:9091",job="pushgateway"} offset 2d
```

You can read more about the offset keyword here:
https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#offset-modifier

Comment: It's not that easy as it seems ;). I don't want to hardcode the label values. Imagine a table of records with different values for `my_label`. I need to have this difference `my_label - 2` for the whole table.

Comment: I edited my answer, seems like I misunderstood your question

Comment: No, again - please note that I am referring to the label NOT the value. I don't care about the metrics timestamp generated by Prometheus as it is a technical date - I need to do calculation based on the value of my label, which is a business date.

Comment: I've edited my question with SQL-like analogy what I would like to achieve.

Comment: I think this could be doable in Grafana with variable declaration, but not in plain PromQL

Comment: Variable declaration is also based on data source, so we end up in the same place... Anyway - thanks for your help! I will have to introduce some workarounds here for now.

Comment: the easiest way would be to calculate it in code and expose it this way, with no use of promql